# Использование Source и Path одновременно при Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, xaml, binding

Имеется конвертер, который принимает некоторый объект и проанализировав его свойства возвращает объект Visiability. Однако обновление должно срабатывать каждый раз, когда меняется некоторое свойство этого объекта. Приведу пример:

```
Visibility="{Binding Source=LoadingModelProcess, 
Path=LoadingModelProcess.InProgress,
Converter={StaticResource ProcessVisiabilityConverter}}">
```

Нужно следующее:
Когда изменится значение поля bool InProgress в объекте LoadingModelProcess, в конвертер прилетел на обработку сам объект LoadingModelProcess. Как это реализовать?

Про MultiBinding знаю, но может есть какое-нибудь другое решение?

Данное решение не помогает:

```
            <TreeView.Visibility>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ProcessVisibilityConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="LoadingModelProcess" />
                    <Binding Path="LoadingModelProcess.InProgress" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </TreeView.Visibility>
```

Comment: Мультибиндинг - самый правильный и чистый способ. Если не хочется писать мультиконвертер для визибилити (это грязно), можно замутить систему универсальных конвертеров (но так будет больше куда).

Comment: @Athari, спасибо, раз это самый правильный способ, то его и буду использовать

Answer (score 3):

`Source` у `Binding` есть всегда, и это не "выходное" значение, а "входное". Когда свойство не задано (равно `null`), то используется "значение по умолчанию" — текущий `DataContext`. Выходное значение у `Binding` одно, и порядок вычисления значения в `Binding` один:

1. `Source` / `RelativeSource` / `ElementName` ("по умолчанию": `DataContext`)
2. `Path` / `XPath` ("по умолчанию": `.`)
3. `Converter` (по умолчанию: `null`)
4. `StringFormat` / автоматический конвертер ("по умолчанию": `null`)

`Source` остаётся и выходным значением только тогда, когда все остальные преобразования в цепочке отсутствуют.

Чтобы подписаться на изменения одного свойства, а получать на выходе  другое, вам нужны различающиеся входы и выходы, а значит, `MultiBinding`.

Минусом является то, что вам может понадобиться написать конвертер `ProcessVisibilityMultiConverter`, что несколько архитектурно неприятно. Самый простой альтернативный способ — реализовать `IMultiConverter` прямо в `ProcessVisibilityConverter`. Самый сложный, но мощный — сделать конвертер, который собирается из других конвертеров, чтобы можно было пробрасывать одно из значений `MultiBinding` в обычный конвертер.

Comment: Реализовал следующим образом (см. обновленный вопрос), но при изменении LoadingModelProcess.InProgress конвертер снова не запускается. Мне необходимо, чтобы изменения в bool InProgress было неким триггером для запуска конвертера, хотя я и анализирую объект LoadingModelProcess в целом

Comment: @БадаловБадал Если конвертер не вызывается, значит, WPF не ловит уведомления об изменении значения свойства. Убедитесь, что при изменении всех влияющих на расчёты свойств бросаются события об изменении через `INotifyPropertyChanged` или `DependencyProperty`. Также вы можете навесить `PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High` на все три биндинга, чтобы полностью отследить все расчёты и отловленные изменения.

Comment: Cобытие из модели об изменении свойства пробрасывается, в этом я уверен и отслеживал дебаггером, в том числе. Так и не разобрался, в чём была причина, поэтому вынес логику в ViewModel и привязался к свойству в нём.